# UITabBar Lifecycle's methods are not fired from background start

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I've have a `UITabBar` controller as main controller, with 2 tabs. Each tab is a `NavigatorViewController` with a `UIViewController` embedded.

If I open the application from background after a previous cold launch, none of the `ViewWillAppear` (`UITabBarController`, `UIViewController`) is fired.

How can I call the lifecycle of UITabBarChildren when user come from backgroud? (IE: From a notification)

Answer (score 1):

That is not in the life cycle because the state of controllers is not changing during background mode or other application events.

You should observe for `applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Listen for application event somewhere early like `ViewDidLoad`
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    // Implement a function that you want to execute when event happen
    @objc func applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification() {
        // Do anything before application Enter Foreground
    }

    // Remove observer when the controller is going to remove to prevent further issues
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer whenever you are navigating to other screens.

Answer (score 0):

When application comes from background non `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` is called for any active vc , you need to listen to app delegate  like `applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

---

```
@objc func applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
  print("To-Do")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `observer` to **`UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`** in your `controllers`.

> Posted shortly before an app leaves the background state on its way to
>   becoming the active app.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.appEnteredFromBackground(_:)),name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
}

@objc func appEnteredFromBackground(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    print("From background")
}
```